# An other smd identification help

Tags: identification, surface-mount

Searched a lot and didnt managed to find this smd . Any suggestion , replacement smd ?
Thanks in advance. (SMD code as pic shows PH69 A 918010 )[image]

Here is an other pic[image]

Comment: Possibly a bcp69 from someone, what's it doing?

Comment: It is very similar to this component https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-790596010-10-pecas-de-transistor-bcp56-16-smd-sot223-nxp-_JM?quantity=1

Comment: +1 simply for an excellent photo

Comment: Could this be it ... https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BUK98180-100A.pdf

Comment: Sorry for the delay... his is from auomoive module and provides earh o an solenoid.I read somewere tha someone replaced i with BSP78 power fet but i want to be shoure if thats ok .

Comment: Ty DerStrom8 ...